# Redirecting old urls to cleaner urls

Tags: python, django, django-views

Just having some problems redirecting urls.

urls.py

```
url(r'^index\.asp$', views.Redirect, name='redirect'),
```

views.py

```
pageID = {
"2145841371" : "/home",
"2145887330" : "/club",
}

def Redirect(request):

pageID = request.GET.get('pageID')
return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect(pageID))
```

Basically what I want it to do is when the user tries a old url (e.g. index.asp?pageID=2145841371) it will redirect them to the new one. Thoughts?

Comment: Please don't use camelcase in Python, it's against PEP8. Same for function name, it should be lowercase. It's a community standard. Here you main problem is that you use `HttpResponseRedirect` and `redirect()` The latter already return the former, so you don't need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
def Redirect(request):
    redirect_map = {
        '2145841371': '/home',
        '2145887330': '/club',
    }
    pageID = request.GET.get('pageID')
    return redirect(redirect_map[pageID])
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't come up with error but it just redirects back to the current page, rather then the specifed url. Much better though!

Comment: Sweet I got it to work, just had to remove redirect. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This will not work. `redirect()` already return a `HttpResponseRedirect`, so no need to add another one. Get rid of it. Plus, this is not very robust: you hardcode urls, you make the mapping at every view call, you have no fallback it no `pageID` is provided or if the pageID doesn't match any URL. And you make a temporary redirection, which may harm SEO. I'm not putting -1, because it's still a helfull answer, but you can improve it.

Comment: @e-satis: I just meant to provide a basic answer. I have no idea how the OP wants to do error handling (does he want to return 404? redirect elsewhere?).

Answer (score 4):

A clean way to do it:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect


# constant name should be uppercased
REDIRECTIONS = {
        '2145841371': reverse('home'),
        '2145887330': reverse('club'),
        'default': '/' # put here the URL to redirect to if mismatch
}

# function names should be lowercased
def redirect_legacy_urlid(request):

    # if no pageID, then default
    pageID = request.GET.get('pageID', 'default') 

    # if pageID doesn't match, then default
    url = REDIRECTIONS.get(pageID, REDIRECTIONS['default'])

    return redirect(url, permanent=True)
```

The `permanent=True` is important, so this way the browsers will cache this and make it a better experience if users comme back from the old URL again. Plus search engine will be able to remap their results. Of course, do it only if the redirection is supposed to be permanent.

Use `reverse()` to get an url from your urls.py schema. It's better than to hardcode the URL, since you can change your mind about this later and you don't want to rewrite it everywhere.

This implies you must use [names in your urls.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#url).

Comment: I just did a similar route with permanent=True and used HttpResponsePermanentRedirect. Also I did have names for each url, but isn't your way the same, as you have to use each url's name rather than their actual url?

Answer (score 0):

I just used `django.shortcuts.redirect` inside the "old" view, redirecting to the "new" view's URL.

```
def oldview(request):
    # figure out what new view to send it to
    return redirect("new/url/", permanent = True)
```

Comment: Yeah I would do it this way but I'm dealing with a lot of old urls so a list of them would be easier to work with.